# Why does my connection to a linux AMI on EC2 get disconnected when I shut my laptop

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is there a way to prevent processes from stopping on the linux AMI when I shut or turn off my computer?  This happens when I am connected via my Terminal on my OSX machine.  Seems like the process should still run regardless of what my computer is doing. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use `nohup` or `screen` to run a process in the background so you can disconnect from it.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935) for using `screen`. Relevant section from the tutorial:

> The other main cool feature of screen is its ability to decouple the
>   terminal emulator from the running programs. This means that you can
>   use screen to keep programs running after you accidentally close the
>   terminal emulator, or even after you log out, and later resume right
>   where you were. It means that the idea of a "session" in which you are
>   running a number of console programs is a free-floating entity that
>   you can bind to any terminal anywhere, or no terminal at all if you
>   want.

If you choose to go the `nohup` route, here is a [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html) for that.